# Reconciling Columns VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a reconciliation sub which will find a value in Spreadsheet A, Column A and return the corresponding value in Column B i.e. Column A = ID123; Column B = HELLO. The procedure will then find the same value in Spreadsheet B, Column A (in this example, ID123) and return the value in Column B. So ideally, I would like these 2 values to be side by side so that I can do a comparison. All I have so far is code that will return values from Column A but I am unable to return Column B. This is essentially a VLookup, but Vlookups have proven to be very consuming in VBA:

```
    Sub findCell()


 Dim ETLCell As String
 Dim mifidCell As String
 Dim last_row_A As Long
 Dim last_row_B As Long
 
 last_row_A = Worksheets("Spreadsheet A").UsedRange.Rows.Count
 last_row_B = Worksheets("Spreadsheet B").UsedRange.Rows.Count
 
 'Loop which returns the TRN beside each column
 For i = 2 To last_row_A

ETLCell = Worksheets("Spreadsheet B").Columns("B:B").Find(What:=Worksheets("Spreadsheet A").Cells(i, 1).Value)
mifidCell = Worksheets("Spreadsheet A").Cells(i, 1).Value

    Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 1).Value = ETLCell
    
    If ETLCell Is Nothing Then
ETLCell = "BLANK"
    Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 2).Value = "False"
    
    Else
    Worksheets("Reconciliation").Cells(i, 2).Value = "True"
    
    End If
        

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Generally speaking, how many rows do you expect to have in each of the Worksheets A and B?

Comment: Currently about 500 but this could vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a different approach than the one that you took to solve this issue. I tried embedding comments into the code to describe what is happening. Try reviewing it and see if you can incorporate it into your workbook, and write back with questions.

I stored the values from sheet B into a dictionary object for efficient lookup. This type of object holds a unique key, and a corresponding value. Then, I can loop over the `Keys` in sheet A, looking for them in sheet B, and then adding the values to the reconciliation.

```
Sub AnalyzeReconciliation()
    Dim sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim sht2 As Worksheet
    Dim shtRecon As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim reconRow As Long
    
    Set sht1 = Worksheets("Worksheet A")
    Set sht2 = Worksheets("Worksheet B")
    Set shtRecon = Worksheets("Reconciliation")
    
    'I don't like using UsedRange. I find it to be unreliable
    'Define the columns that you need, and find the last row
    'using a method call similar to below
    Set rng1 = sht1.Range("A2:B" & sht1.Range("A" & sht1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Set rng2 = sht2.Range("A2:B" & sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    'Get a dictionary object holding unique values from sheet 2
    'In my case, column A holds the Id, and column B holds the value
    Set oDict = GetDictionary(rng2, 1, 2)
    
    reconRow = 0
    
    'Loop over each cel in sheet 1, column 1
    'Look for the value in column 1 in the sheet 2 dictionary
    'object, and then reconcile
    For Each cel In Intersect(rng1, sht1.Columns(1))
        'Get the next avail row in reconciliation sheet
        reconRow = reconRow + 1
        shtRecon.Range("A" & reconRow).Value = cel.Value
        
        'Recon column B holds value from sheet 1, column B
        shtRecon.Range("B" & reconRow).Value = cel.Offset(, 1).Value
        
        'If Id is found in Sheet B dictionary, then take the value
        'otherwise, write "blank" in column C
        If oDict.exists(cel.Value) Then
            shtRecon.Range("C" & reconRow).Value = oDict(cel.Value)
        Else
            shtRecon.Range("C" & reconRow).Value = "BLANK"
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub

'Function stores a range into a dictionary
'Param inputRange takes a range to be stored
'Param idColumn takes the column of the range to be used as the ID
'   e.g. if idColumn = 2, and inputRange("C1:F10"), then column D
'        is used for ID
'Param valueColumn points to the column in range used for the value
Function GetDictionary(inputRange As Range, idColumn As Long, valueColumn As Long) As Object
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    
    Set oDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set sht = inputRange.Parent
    
    For Each cel In Intersect(inputRange, inputRange.Columns(idColumn))
        If Not oDict.exists(cel.Value) Then
            oDict.Add cel.Value, sht.Cells(cel.Row, valueColumn).Value
        End If
    Next cel
    
    Set GetDictionary = oDict
End Function
```

Comment: You've made my day @basodre! Worked a treat.

Comment: Great! Good luck with it.

Comment: would you know how I could incorporate a third set of values here to do a 3-way reconciliation with Worksheet C?

Comment: @DannyO'Sullivan It sounds doable, but I'm not sure exactly what you'd need to do. Can you provide more details? (If it doesn't fit into one of these comments, you can edit you original post. Just leave a comment here as well so that I get a notification that you edited the post).